# Mongodb query for condition on an array

Tags: mongodb

I have an an list of student which contain scores array of object, for example:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a6c4542d0de393d2739979"),
        "student_id" : 0,
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 76
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 65
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 58
                }
        ],
        "class_id" : 438
}
```

I need to get student from collection, based on type and respective score with and condition for example

score greater than 60 in exam and

score greater than 50 in quiz and

score greater than 45 in homework

currently i'm trying the following query

```
db.students.find({$and: [{'scores.type': 'exam'}, {'scores.score': {$gt: 60}}]});
```

but its not working for single condition.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create query like this using `$and` and then create condition for each score type using `$elemMatch` and `$gt`

```
{
    $and: [
        {scores: {$elemMatch: {'type': 'exam','score': {$gt: 60}}}},
        {scores: {$elemMatch: {'type': 'quiz','score': {$gt: 50}}}},
        {scores: {$elemMatch: {'type': 'homework','score': {$gt: 45}}}}
    ]
}
```